# Dataset vs UnitOfWork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dataset, unit-of-work

I've read a [topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714955(v=vs.113).aspx) which contains this quote

> "However, DataSet objects model a disconnected subset of the
>   underlying database. The unit of work pattern exhibits the same
>   behavior, but works with business objects and domain objects that are
>   isolated from data access code and unaware of the database."

I'm confused when reading that text and wonder what different characteristics are of DataSet and UnitOfWork? What does "Isolated from data access code and unaware of the database" mean?

Answer (score 2):

It means that the data model you're working with in these cases is not directly tied to the 'live' data in SQL Server.  If someone else commits a CRUD operation on the server that would have impacted your `DataSet`, you won't see it reflected in the `DataSet` itself.

The reference to the Unit of Work pattern is meant to further explain what this is like.  You can find a larger tutorial/explanation on the Unit of Work pattern [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/581487/Unit-of-Work-Design-Pattern) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).  The basic idea is you keep an in-memory representation of your data that you do multiple operations on, and commit your final changes as a single large transaction at the end of your "unit" of work.  This allows you to perform multiple operations (that might be expensive to commit individually back to the database) in memory, and then just commit the final version(s) of your changes rather than each and every individual step.